# How to set classname for <li> tag in wordpress menu?

Tags: menus

I am using.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

to get menu from WordPress.

It returns the menus with `<ul> and <li>` structure.
How can i set class name for every `<li>` tag uniquely.

Comment: there's a filter you can use to do this: `nav_menu_css_class`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS class for the menu.
Under "Screen Options", flag "**CSS Classes**", under "Show Advanced Properties".

Then, for every menu item, you have an additional input that is named "CSS Classes"

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to write your own walker class for it and pass it as an argument, but I must admit that's not too straight forward if you are not too familiar with wordpress development.

I would solve it like this:

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('your_menu_slug_or_id');        
$class = '';
$count = count($menu_items);
$i = 0;

foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    $class = 'item-'.(++$i);
?>
    <li class="<?php echo $class?>">
        <!-- add menu title and url here as you please -->
    </li>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you buddy - http://wpveda.com/add-custom-classes-wpnavmenu-condition/

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for needing custom classes?

WordPress menus include a number of classes on the `<li>` elements when the function is run and should be everything you need to work with.